# Why is 'df' hanging?

Tags: mount, utilities, disk-usage

I have recently been having problems running `df`, where it just *hangs*. Here's `strace` output, and in it, you'll see that I killed since it was just sitting there:

```
$ strace /bin/df
execve("/bin/df", ["/bin/df"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8d03000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7840000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=90781, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 90781, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7829000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\240o\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1401000, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1415544, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb76cf000
mprotect(0xb7822000, 4096, PROT_NONE)   = 0
mmap2(0xb7823000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x153) = 0xb7823000
mmap2(0xb7826000, 10616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7826000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76ce000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb76ce8d0, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
mprotect(0xb7823000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb785e000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb7829000, 90781)               = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8d03000
brk(0x8d24000)                          = 0x8d24000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1534656, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1534656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7557000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/mtab", O_RDONLY)             = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=708, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb783f000
read(3, "/dev/sda6 / ext4 rw,errors=remou"..., 4096) = 708
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb783f000, 4096)                = 0
statfs64("/", 84, {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=4805813, f_bfree=3325193, f_bavail=3081072, f_files=1220608, f_ffree=1007617, f_fsid={-1624337824, -871214780}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb783f000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb783f000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_ZA.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_ZA/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs64("/lib/init/rw", 84, {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=1280, f_bfree=1280, f_bavail=1280, f_files=215959, f_ffree=215956, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/run", 84, {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=102000, f_bfree=101823, f_bavail=101823, f_files=215959, f_ffree=215559, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/sys", 84, {f_type="SYSFS_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/dev", 84, {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=508762, f_bfree=508762, f_bavail=508762, f_files=213490, f_ffree=213031, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/run/shm", 84, {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=203999, f_bfree=203816, f_bavail=203816, f_files=215959, f_ffree=215955, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/dev/pts", 84, {f_type="DEVPTS_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/boot", 84, {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=1024, f_blocks=188403, f_bfree=150550, f_bavail=140822, f_files=48768, f_ffree=48525, f_fsid={-655942775, 1382872797}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=1024}) = 0
statfs64("/home", 84, {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=66535124, f_bfree=6683145, f_bavail=3303357, f_files=16900096, f_ffree=16633097, f_fsid={-515912651, 307591087}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/sys/fs/fuse/connections", 84, {f_type=0x65735543, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs64("/home/wena/temp/mount", 84, ^C <unfinished ...>
```

Another tool that fails is `gnome-system-monitor`, which also seems to hang immediately after being launched.

Comment: My version of coreutils is 8.13-2, running in Debian Unstable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I used `sshfs` to mount a directory from some ssh server, and my network connection was lost. It appears `df` was trying to list that mount and instead of failing gracefully, it just got stuck :(

Comment: You can perform a lazy unmount with `umount -l /path-to/mount` to get around this.

Comment: It's not failing gracefully because it's not failing at all: it's patiently waiting for the server to reply.

Comment: does `df -l` work?

Comment: @Gilles: Classic example of the Halting Problem.

Comment: Also happens with SMB mounts btw. Very relevant: [The Trouble with Mounting](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/engineering/the-trouble-with-mounting/). And [stat system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call))

Answer (score 16):

The most common cause of software like `df` hanging is when they're trying to read from a disk that isn't responsing properly.

Check the output from `dmesg` to see if this is the case -- a flaky drive will toss out a great deal of errors.

Unfortunately, this tends to be a hardware problem and you may be looking at having to replace the entire drive. I recommend you make backups of everything you can.

Comment: If you are in this situation you can `umount -lf /your/mount/point`.

Answer (score 10):

Another case not covered in the above answers:

In my case, using `strace df`, I found that `df` was hanging when trying to `statfs` the `keybase` filesystem:

```
$ strace df
...   # many lines omitted for brevity
statfs("/run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs", <--- hangs here
^Cstrace: Process 17510 detached
```

logging out (and re-logging in) to `keybase` solved this particular issue:

```
$ keybase logout
$ df  # doesn't hang anymore
...

$ keybase login
$ df  # still ok
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Bumping @AbishekA's comment to an answer for visibility: for the problem described in the accepted answer (an inaccessible network-mounted directory), the solution is using

```
df -l
```

to only list local directories.

Answer (score 4):

Not the case here, but for the record, note that some versions of the GNU implementation of `df` (since version 7.3, fixed in 8.29 ([with this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=b04ce61958c1f1fc264950f8d3b6058f640ee491))) hang on readable fifo/named pipe files  that have no writer, as they try to open them, as seen in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29038

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ strace df fifo
[...]
open("fifo", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY  # hanging there
```

Comment: What is the fix to this issue?

Comment: @karthik101, see edit: upgrade to 8.29 or don't use df on fifos.

Comment: installed from source, works great.

Answer (score 3):

My root cause was an unusual one but I'll mention it anyway in case anyone makes the same mistake. I was using `cifs` in `/etc/auto.direct` on Ubuntu 16.04.4 (recently upgraded to from 16.04). I did not add `vers=1.0`.

Backward compatibility - one of the biggest myths in software.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I had mounted a nfs which was unreachable and `df -H` hangs/stuck
To solve this I listed all my nfs mount points

```bash
mount -v | grep nfs
```

then
I unmounted the nfs from directory

```bash
umount -fl /path/path/path
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue restart below service worked for me.

```
systemctl restart proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the very same problem, but with a slightly different cause. In my case, a `guestmount` was blocking access to a directory. Naturally, it wasn't referenced anywhere in `/etc/fstab`, and so I couldn't figure out why `df` would hang.

The solution was to run `strace df` which showed exactly what directory was causing problems. With `ps -aux | grep <directory path>`, I found that it was mounted with `guestmount`. As soon as I ran `kill -9` on the `guestmount` process and unmounted the directory, `df` could work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

To add to the general troubleshooting-ness of this question. I found out that I had a on of bind-mounts which had been run many times on top of eachother (I think).

Iterating through these 32845-ish bind-mounts turned out to be slow. :P

```
# mount -v
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
...
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on /home/odin/Work/ghrunners/base type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on /home/odin/Work/ghrunners/base_bindmount type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on /home/odin/Work/ghrunners/base type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on /home/odin/Work/ghrunners/base_bindmount type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on /home/odin/Work/ghrunners/base type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on /home/odin/Work/ghrunners/base_bindmount type
... 32k times
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/cdc21aeb3333 type nsfs (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
root@enn:~#
```

Doing an un-mount: `umount /home/odin/Work/ghrunners/base` fixed it.