# How to check whether mounted volume is still accessible?

Tags: mount

I have a NAS that I run out of my home. I always keep a directory on the NAS (~/mydata) mounted on my laptop (at ~/nas). When I am at home, I mount the volume over the LAN. When I am not at home, I mount it over the Internet. I would like to automate the mounting process to:

- (a) Mount when I connect to a network
- (b) Unmount when I disconnect from a network
- (c) Mount when I log in

I have a launchd specification that runs a script whenever a network change (switch, connection, or disconnection) occurs. But I can't figure out how to detect whether a previously mounted volume is accessible. The problem is that once my volume is mounted, even if I disconnect from the network and the mounted volume is no longer accessible (either because I used a `.local` hostname that only works on my home network or because there simply is no network connection at all), the OS doesn't seem to know this. I've tried a couple tests:

- `mount`: the output of argumentless `mount` continues to show the mounted volume, with no indication of inaccessibility
- `cd ~/nas`: hangs
- `df`: hangs
- `umount`: hangs

I am on macOS and am using `sshfs` to do the mounting. How can I check whether a mounted volume is still accessible?

Comment: If your question is related only to `sshfs` you should have a look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/6709/sshfs-mount-that-survives-disconnect) . IMHO the best way is to let `mount`, with right timeout/reconnection settings, to take care of it.

Answer (score -1):

To check whether a mount already exists or not use the following command and check for fuse.sshfs :

```
mount | grep fuse.sshfs
```

Also to mount or unmount file system refer this [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.fuse.8.html) page.Try unmounting it and mount again.More of this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/why-is-df-hanging/21200)

Comment: Thanks for your response sai. A few problems though: (1) as I explain in the question, the output of `mount` continues to show the mounted volume after it has been disconnected. (2) the `mount` output indicating the mount doesn't even show `fuse.sshfs`; instead it shows `USER@HOST:/host/path on /target/path (osxfuse, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by smackesey)`